# Handle an Event in an AS file that was dispatched from a Mobile Spark Component

Tags: actionscript-3, mobile, air

I have an mxml file called HomeView.mxml in a mobile app built using Flash Builder 4.6. In that HomeView.mxml I have an HSlider, which is dispatching events when the thumb is moved. What I'm trying to do is to listen for that valueCommit event in an .as file elsewhere in the project.

Whenever the thumb moves, an event is dispatched in HomeView.mxml:

```
    hSlider.dispatchEvent(new FlexEvent("valueCommit", true));
```

I can handle that event in HomeView.mxm, but not in an .as class called view.as

In view.as I import the FlexEvent and I then have, in addedToStageHandler:

```
    stage.addEventListener(FlexEvent.VALUE_COMMIT, commitHandler);
```

Then there's a simple Handler:

```
    private function commitHandler(e:FlexEvent):void
    {
        trace("committed!");
    }
```

But this code never runs. I do have a handler in the HomeView.mxml file which handles the event, but for other reasons I need to handle it in view.as as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One of the cause is you have anywhere `stopPropagation` or `stopImmediatePropagation` methods. It is possible that this methods located in a code of the HSlider component. You may try to dispatch a custom event which doesn't extends the FlexEvent.

Comment: thanks, yes, that's what I've been working on as a workaround.  I don't have stopPropagation or stopImmediatePropagation anywhere. You'd think there would be a way just to listen for the FlexEvent elsewhere....